# WSOD on node edit/view pages only after migration - subdomain multisite

Tags: migrations, multi-sites, wsod, subsites

just migrated my company's website, foo.com, to a new server.  It is a multisite installation with an intranet, intranet.foo.com, installed at /sites/intranet.foo.com.  Everything migrated successfully except for one thing: node view and edit pages are not loading on the intranet (whereas admin pages, view pages, etc., are loading perfectly).

I tried a blank node.tpl.php and the page still didn't load, so the error must be elsewhere.

I have php error reporting enabled in index.php – 

but I don't see any php errors (is this even possible - for some types of error?  Anyway I have a ticket open asking the host to enable error reporting in php.ini).

I don't see any WSOD documentation on drupal.org that pertains to this specific predicament (node page WSOD only).

Does anyone have any ideas about server settings that could be causing this to happen on the new server?  Or database issues that could be affecting node pages only?  Or if it is a php code error, where would it be such that it would break only node edit and view pages?

Answer (score 1):

You have to also turn on display_errors (see the examples section of http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php ).

Usually when display_errors is off php is configured to log errors to some file. You might want to find that file and look at it.

My guess would be that some php-module is missing on that server and some drupal-module that is active on node-edit forms tries to use a function from that php-module.

Comment: You, sir, are good.  I systematically disabled the modules one by one and found that the Pear Wiki filter was breaking the node pages.  Strangely, I did think of this and enable the relevant pear packages in cPanel, but I must have missed something or Drupal can't find them on the server for some reason.  Thank you!